# trigger child plan after both parents in bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

I'm wondering if I can get some help in relation to Bamboo. I am very very new to this system.

How I can trigger child plan after both parents are completed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to trigger multiple child builds after the completion of a parent build, however I'm not sure if multiple-parent dependencies are explicitly supported.

One possibility (depending on how strict your build architecture is) would be to setup one parent build as the child of another, so at the completion of the first parent build, the second would commence. Then, following its completion, the child build begins.

Parent A's child is Parent B, then
Parent B's child is your Child plan.

See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-bamboo/working-with-builds/setting-up-plan-build-dependencies for a limited overview of dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, but I need both parents to trigger on at the same time.